# Why is my sap.m.Page empty and footer is at top instead of bottom?

Tags: sapui5

I made a very simple UI5 application with one Page with a footer. But the footer is being displayed at top of the page. I expect it to be sticky to the bottom of the page.

```js
return new sap.m.Page({
  title: "test",
  content: oForm1,
  footer: new sap.m.Bar({/*...*/})
});
```

Also my form is not being displayed because the height of the form is zero pixels, although the content is there.

```js
var oForm1 = new sap.ui.layout.form.Form("F1",{
  title: new sap.ui.core.Title({text: "(Un)Loading Checklist"}),
  layout: new sap.ui.layout.form.GridLayout(),
  formContainers: [
    new sap.ui.layout.form.FormContainer("F1C1", {
      title: "Person data",
      formElements: []
    })
  ]
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page Is Blank Without Throwing Any Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922382/page-is-blank-without-throwing-any-errors)

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951902/5846045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the page into a sap.m.App control.

[Example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/m/App.html)