# Page Is Blank Without Throwing Any Errors

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to display few tiles in a tile container which fetches data from a dummy JSON file. I have coded exactly shown in [this sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TileContainer/code). But my page appears empty. Also it doesn't show any errors in the console. Below are the snippets of my code.

#### View1.controller.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("AdminMovie.controller.View1", {

  });
});
```

#### View1.view.xml

```xml
<mvc:View
  displayBlock="true" 
  controllerName="AdminMovie.controller.View1"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
>
  <Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="false">
    <mvc:XMLView viewName="AdminMovie.view.TileContainer"/>
    <footer>
      <OverflowToolbar id="otbFooter">
        <ToolbarSpacer/>
        <Button type="Accept" text="Add New Movie"/>
      </OverflowToolbar>
    </footer>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

#### TileContailner.view.xml

```xml
<mvc:View
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  controllerName="AdminMovie.controller.TileContainer"
>
  <App>
    <pages>
      <Page
        showHeader="false"
        enableScrolling="false"
        title="Stark"
      >
        <TileContainer id="container"
          tileDelete="handleTileDelete"
          tiles="{/MovieCollection}"
        >
          <HBox>
            <StandardTile
              icon="{icon}"
              type="{type}"
              number="{number}"
              numberUnit="{numberUnit}"
              title="{title}"
              info="{info}"
              infoState="{infoState}"
            />
          </HBox>
        </TileContainer>
        <OverflowToolbar>
          <Toolbar>
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <Button
              text="Edit"
              press=".handleEditPress"
            />
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
          </Toolbar>
        </OverflowToolbar>
      </Page>
    </pages>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

#### TileContainer.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "jquery.sap.global",
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("AdminMovie.controller.TileContainer", {
    onInit: function(evt) {
      // set mock model
      var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("AdminMovie", "/MovieCollection.json");
      var oModel = new JSONModel(sPath);
      this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    },

    handleEditPress: function(evt) {
      var oTileContainer = this.byId("container");
      var newValue = !oTileContainer.getEditable();
      oTileContainer.setEditable(newValue);
      evt.getSource().setText(newValue ? "Done" : "Edit");
    },

    handleTileDelete: function(evt) {
      var tile = evt.getParameter("tile");
      evt.getSource().removeTile(tile);
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**⚠️ For other readers:** if you're **not** using a `TileContainer`, see my previous answer for general solutions **→ https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951902/5846045**

## Causes for empty `TileContainer`

  ### Unexpected child control
  Besides the [missing root control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951902/5846045), the `<TileContainer>` in your code contains a list of HBoxes.
  > ```xml
  > <TileContainer>
  >   <HBox> <!-- ❌ Wrong aggregation child! -->
  >     <StandardTile />
  > ```
  The default [aggregation of `TileContainer`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.TileContainer#aggregations) is, however, a control that is derived from `sap.m.Tile`.
  [image: UI5 TileContainer aggregation]
  Hence, you should be getting the following error message in the browser console:
  > Uncaught Error: "Element sap.m.HBox#__hbox1" is not valid for aggregation "tiles" of Element sap.m.TileContainer#__xmlview1--container
  Please, remove the `<HBox>` as the binding template:
  ```xml
  <TileContainer>
    <StandardTile /> <!-- ✔️ -->
  ```
  ### `TileContainer` contains only one `Tile`
  There was a [bug (issue #1813)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1813) in the `TileContainer` which failed making the aggregation visible **in Chrome** (works in Firefox) if there was only a single `Tile`. The fix is delivered with OpenUI5 version 1.56+, 1.54.2+, 1.52.8+, 1.50.9+, 1.48.19+, and 1.46.2+.

Answer (score 3):

## Cause

The root view is **missing a root control** or the **`height` of the parent HTML elements is not set to `100%`.** The child elements cannot be rendered in full size.

## Resolution

### For Standalone or Top-Level Applications

Add **[`sap.m.App`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.App)** (or `sap.m.SplitApp` in case of a master-detail layout) **once** in the entire application project to your root view:

```xml
<!-- Root view (typically "App.view.xml") -->
<mvc:View controllerName="..."
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  displayBlock="true"
>
  <App id="topLevelApp"> <!-- Not in any other views! -->
    <pages>
      <!-- ... -->
    </pages>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Root controls such as `sap.m.App`, `sap.m.SplitApp`, and `sap.m.Shell` write:

- a bunch of properties into the header of the HTML document e.g. the viewport meta tag via [`sap/ui/util/Mobile.init`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/module:sap/ui/util/Mobile#methods/sap/ui/util/Mobile.init).
- **`height: 100%` to all its parent elements** by default (unless `isTopLevel` is disabled). <sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/a6fdf7bd9e1766b9caad7eb80963b239f8ab7a21/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/App.js#L190-L217)</sup>

The reason why the [linked sample](https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.StandardTile/sample/sap.m.sample.TileContainer) is working, is that the control `sap.m.App` was already added in *index.html*. The samples shown in the Demo Kit, however, often miss *index.html* in the code page to be shown which can be confusing.

### For Nested or Embedded Applications

If you're developing an app that is to be rendered within an an existing app, keep in mind that the top-level app might come already with one root control (`sap.m.App` with `isTopLevel` enabled or `sap.m.SplitApp`) in its root view. I.e. in this case:

1. **Add `height="100%"` to the View node** of the root view definition, **and**
2. Either use `<App isTopLevel="false">` or replace the `<App>` with `<NavContainer>`.

```xml
<!-- Root view (typically "App.view.xml") -->
<mvc:View controllerName="..."
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  displayBlock="true"
  height="100%"
> <!-- ↑ Set height="100%" -->
  <App isTopLevel="false"> <!-- or:
  <NavContainer> if the UI5 version is below 1.91 -->
    <pages>
      <!-- ... -->
    </pages> <!--
  </NavContainer> -->
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Otherwise, not using the `isTopLevel="false"` will cause the footer area of the embedded app to be pushed out of the viewport. This is a common issue e.g. for the views that are intended to [extend the standard SAP Fiori app "My Inbox"](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_S4HANA_ON-PREMISE/8308e6d301d54584a33cd04a9861bc52/29200d57c62e017ee10000000a441470.html) since the app already contains one root control as a top-level UI element. Refer to [SAP KBA #3218822](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/3218822).