# When will Component.js be loaded?

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to run a SAPUI5 application. I created a view with a view piecharts and add them in `index.html` to the body by referring to its ID `content`

```html
<script>
  var app = new sap.m.App();
  var page = sap.ui.view({
    viewName: "...",
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
  });
  app.addPage(page);
  app.placeAt("content");
</script>
```

My problem now is that the `Component.js` isn't called. So I have no chance of using Routing since the Router isn't initialized.

I tried some different ways, like this:

```html
<script>
  sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
    new sap.m.Shell({
      app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
        height: "100%",
        name: "vizFrame.gettingStarted.demoVizFrame"
      })
    }).placeAt("content");
  });
</script>
```

After this approach, the `Component.js` got triggered, but the page is empty. The content of my root view isn't displayed.

#### manifest.json

```json
{
  "_version": "1.12.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "id": "vizFrame.gettingStarted.demoVizFrame",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "applicationVersion": {
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "sourceTemplate": {
      "id": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
      "version": "1.40.12"
    }
  },
  "sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "icons": {
      "icon": "",
      "favIcon": "",
      "phone": "",
      "phone@2": "",
      "tablet": "",
      "tablet@2": ""
    },
    "deviceTypes": {
      "desktop": true,
      "tablet": true,
      "phone": true
    }
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    "flexEnabled": false,
    "rootView": {
      "viewName": "vizFrame.gettingStarted.demoVizFrame.view.VizChart",
      "type": "XML"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "minUI5Version": "1.60.1",
      "libs": {
        "sap.ui.layout": {},
        "sap.ui.core": {},
        "sap.m": {}
      }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
      "compact": true,
      "cozy": true
    },
    "models": {
      "i18n": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
        "settings": {
          "bundleName": "vizFrame.gettingStarted.demoVizFrame.i18n.i18n"
        }
      }
    },
    "resources": {
      "css": [
        {
          "uri": "css/style.css"
        }
      ]
    },
    "routing": {
      "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "async": true,
        "viewPath": "vizFrame.gettingStarted.demoVizFrame.view",
        "controlAggregation": "pages",
        "controlId": "app",
        "clearControlAggregation": false
      },
      "routes": [
        {
          "name": "RouteVizChart",
          "pattern": "RouteVizChart",
          "target": ["TargetVizChart"]
        },
        {
          "pattern": "detail",
          "name": "detail",
          "target": "detail"
        }
      ],
      "targets": {
        "TargetVizChart": {
          "viewType": "XML",
          "transition": "slide",
          "clearControlAggregation": false,
          "viewId": "VizChart",
          "viewName": "VizChart"
        },
        "testView": {
          "viewType": "XML",
          "viewName": "testView",
          "viewId": "testView",
          "viewLevel": 2
        },
        "detail": {
          "viewType": "XML",
          "viewName": "detailView"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Component.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
  "sap/ui/Device",
  "vizFrame/gettingStarted/demoVizFrame/model/models"
], function (UIComponent, Device, models) {
  "use strict";

  return UIComponent.extend("vizFrame.gettingStarted.demoVizFrame.Component", {
    metadata: {
      manifest: "json"
    },

    init: function () {
      UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
      this.getRouter().initialize();
      this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
    }
  });
});
```

#### VizChart.view.xml

This is the root view where only the page title gets displayed:

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="vizFrame.gettingStarted.demoVizFrame.controller.VizChart"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls"
  xmlns:chart="sap.suite.ui.commons"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
>
  <Page title="Übersicht">
    <l:VerticalLayout
      width="100%"
      class="gridWrapper">
      <l:Grid containerQuery="true">
        <viz:VizFrame xmlns="sap.viz" id="l100" width="100%" selectData="onDataClick" />
        <viz:VizFrame xmlns="sap.viz" id="l300" width="100%" selectData="onDataClick" />
        <viz:VizFrame xmlns="sap.viz" id="l400" width="100%" selectData="onDataClick" />
        <viz:VizFrame xmlns="sap.viz" id="l430" width="100%" selectData="onDataClick" />
        <viz:VizFrame xmlns="sap.viz" id="l499" width="100%" selectData="onDataClick" />
      </l:Grid>
    </l:VerticalLayout>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topic *[App Initialization: What Happens When an App Is Started?](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/d2f58695fce3476f92fdfc07c9e8f7c6)* explains which files are loaded in which order generally. In most cases, a `Component` is loaded with its descriptor (`manifest.json`) once the `ComponentContainer` is instantiated.

---

About the issue with the page being empty, see my other answer in [stackoverflow.com/a/50951902](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951902/5846045).
In your case, the root view is **missing a root control** (e.g. `sap.m.App`). So it should be:

```xml
<!-- Root view -->
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <App id="app" xmlns="sap.m">
    <!-- Leave this block empty if Router should be used. Otherwise, continue.. -->
    <Page title="Übersicht">
      <!-- content -->
    </Page>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

In your 1st snippet, you could see the page content because there was already `sap.m.App`.

Answer (score 2):

- `ComponentContainer` loads `component.js` file from `index.html`
- `component.js` loads component descriptor(manifest.json - application descriptor file to declare dependencies) which is referenced in the file.
- `component.js` create root view, default and resource(i18n) model.

**index.html**

```
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
    new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
        name: "ABC.AppName"
    }).placeAt("content");
});
```

**component.js**

```
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("ABC.AppName.Component", {
    metadata : {
        includes: [jQuery.device.is.phone ? "assets/css/mStyle.css" : "assets/css/dStyle.css"]
    },
    createContent: function () {
        // create root view
        var oView = sap.ui.view({
            id: "app",
            viewName: "ABC.AppName.ViewFolder.App",
            type: "JS",
            viewData: { component: this },
        });

        i18nGlobal = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
            bundleUrl: "i18n/i18n.properties",
            bundleLocale: "de" 
        });

        oView.setModel(i18nGlobal, "i18n");
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(i18nGlobal, "i18n");      

        return oView;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, but is there anything else i need to do, since only the page title is being loaded, but not the content?

Comment: Thanks for your example! I already got a .viev.xml and it's also loaded, but only the Page title and nothing from inside the <content>-tag is loaded. Any Advice? I added my view to the question.

Comment: Just to verify, check the browser console if any error are there, also you can add some content inside `<content>` tag apart for the `viz`. Means after the `<content>` tag just use `<Bar><contentMiddle><Button text="Accept" type="Accept" /></contentMiddle></Bar>` and see the content is visible or not

Comment: I tried and the button isn't visible... There is also no error in the console.

Comment: Try to remove all the content expect `<content><Bar><contentMiddle><Button text="Accept" type="Accept" /></contentMiddle></Bar></content>` and see whether the content is visible or not

Comment: If i change the index.html to this:
<script>
      var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"id_vizChart"});
            var page = sap.ui.view({id:"id_vizChart",
                                        viewName:"vizFrame.gettingStarted.demoVizFrame.view.VizChart",
                                        type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
            app.addPage(page);
            app.placeAt("content");
    </script>

The viz's are shown, but the Component.js isn't triggered.

Comment: Also nothing visible if I remove everything except the button

Comment: Do i need to add the VizChart view somehow in the Component.js maybe?

Comment: You can try that as well.

Comment: Could you provide me an example? I can't find any way to add the view inside the `Component.js`

Comment: i resetet the whole project and it's now calling the component.js.

Comment: View is loaded now? Are you loading the view from `Component.js`?

Comment: No, i used your `index.html` example. Problem now is, that it isn't fullscreen now anymore, but as long as the Router is working I'm currently ok with that. Thanks for your help.