# Flexible column layout shows an empty page

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create an app based on Flexible Column Layout that is described on the page https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout/sample/sap.f.sample.FlexibleColumnLayoutWithFullscreenPage/code/webapp/controller/FlexibleColumnLayout.controller.js.

When I run the app, it shows me an empty page. The source code is hosted on https://github.com/softshipper/fclpoc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page Is Blank Without Throwing Any Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922382/page-is-blank-without-throwing-any-errors)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951902/5846045

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happened to me many times already. Basically, your root view does not have a "Root" element, like the `sap.m.App` control.

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.f"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:m="sap.m"
    displayBlock="true"
    controllerName="io.example.fclpoc.controller.App"
    height="100%">
    <m:App>
        <m:pages>
            <FlexibleColumnLayout id="fcl"
                stateChange="onStateChanged"
                layout="{/layout}"
                backgroundDesign="Solid">
            </FlexibleColumnLayout>
        </m:pages>
    </m:App>
</mvc:View>
```

Keep in mind that the `sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout` is a layout control and should be added inside a kind of container. Inside the samples of the UI5 SDK, the container is part of the "Samples" tab itself. In other words, it's not always part of the sample code itself.

By the way, I have just done a pull request on your GitHub repo.