# SAPUI5 in vscode - After debug project don't show any errors but didn't show all page

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, vscode-debugger, sap-web-ide

I am making a project in VS Code with sapui5 extensions for SAP WEB IDE.
I made a view and when I debug project didn't return any errors, but at the browser only appears the page name.

This is my view code:

```html
<mvc:View
    controllerName="opensap.launchpadSeidor.launchpad.controller.Login"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="true"
    xmlns="sap.m"

>

    <Page id="page" title="cenas" >
    <MessagePage showHeader="false"
             text="Detalhes de clientes"
             enableFormattedText="true"
             description="Escolha um cliente da lista ou adicione novo cliente carregando no botão abaixo da mesma"
             icon="sap-icon://message-warning"> 
          </MessagePage>
    </Page> 
</mvc:View>
```

And this is the result in the browser:

[image]

I don't know what is happening. Yesterday I finished a project with the same configurations and everything was OK. Today nothing runs! What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page Is Blank Without Throwing Any Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922382/page-is-blank-without-throwing-any-errors)

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951902/5846045 from the above linked question. The app might be missing a root control. I.e. simply add `<App>...</App>` as the top control in your root view.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can put it in an `<App>` container like below.

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="my.Controller"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  displayBlock="true"
>
  <App>
    <!-- Your Message Page -->
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Or just put the `<MessagePage>` directly under view.